# Buscador de Twitters

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api

Hola chicos tengo una consulta un poco urgente, resulta que me están pidiendo que implemente un buscador de Twitters, en que se basará? en lo siguiente:

Buscador de twitters
Objetivos del programa
-    recuperar la mayor cantidad posible de  direcciones de twitter a partir de una palabra clave, que será el nombre de uno de los 19 departamentos (provincias) del Uruguay o del nombre de alguna de las 470 poblaciones (ciudades, pueblos, villas, barrios, etc.) del país o sus respectivos gentilicios, que estarán indizados en una tabla. Ej.: Artigas, artiguense, etc. o Bella Unión, Caraguatá, San Ramón, Montevideo, etc.
-    disponer las direcciones recuperadas en un listado que permita seleccionar las direcciones que se deseen abrir en forma automatizada para recuperar los mensajes colgados por el usuario que figura en la dirección del twitter.
-    abrir de forma automatizada las direcciones de twitter seleccionadas de modo que todos los mensajes de casa usuario queden organizados en un solo documento que se pueda archivar en una carpeta con una etiqueta determinada.

Una aplicación que capture las direcciones de Twitter que hagan referencia a la localidad del usuario. Las georeferencias y las localizaciones de GPS no interesan porque dan la ubicación del usuario en el momento que cuelga el mensaje, es necesario ir al perfil del usuario, donde coloca, muchas veces, su localidad, su fecha de nacimiento, etc. 
Debe capturar usuarios que hayan puesto una palabra en específico en el perfil que luce al comienzo de la página, las búsquedas estarán orientadas a nombres de localidades. Pero básicamente es eso.

¿Que recomiendan ustedes para llevar a cabo esto? quedo atento y muchas gracias.

Comment: Lectura obligada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar Twython, soporta la opción de stream por si deseas hacer búsquedas en "vivo" es decir, que te siga arrojando respuestas en tiempo real

Hay varios tutoriales de como trabajar con twython

En [este link](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/streaming_api.html) puedes ver la documentación de twython y un ejemplo para hacer un stream

Comment: El twitter tiene una dificultad hasta ahora no superada que es que limita muchísimo el tiempo de búsqueda, y eso hace que los resultados sean muy pobres ¿Esta opción me ayuda con eso?

Comment: Si, cuando haces consultas una por una el sistema te restringe a 15 solicitudes por no recuerdo cuanto tiempo (Que es muy poco) pero cuando habres un stream lo que haces es tener comunicación en tiempo real, es como hacer una búsqueda con filtros, mientras no cierres el canal seguiras obteniendo resultados mientras los usuarios twittean

Comment: Oh excelente opción, soy totalmente nuevo en web pero buscaré algún tutorial para apoyarme y empezar a desarrolarla

Comment: En el link que te dejé encontrarás la página de documentación de Twython y justo en esa parte habla del stream y hay un ejemplo que podrías copiar y pegar. Algo muy importante es que vas a tener que hacer una cuenta de desarrollador en twitter ya que vas a hacer una "app" para filtrar tu búsqueda en twitter

Comment: Si eso estuve leyendo amigo, que debo crear la cuenta para poder consumir la Api sin ningún problema, ¿cuánto crees que me llevará tener esa app lista? ah y otra cosa una vez obtenidos los datos que hago en stream ¿los puedo guardar ordenados en una tabla de excel?

Comment: Ya teniendo la Api el código es como 10 líneas o menos, en la página que te mandé al final viene la linea stream.statuses.filter(track='twitter') en lugar de 'twitter' tu pones lo que quieres buscar y ya. Esos datos te los va a poner en la consola donde estes ejecutando Python, si quieres guardarlos en algun lugar de forma automática vas a tener que crear un archivo desde python e ir escribiendo resultado tras resultado

Comment: Ok perfecto, muchísimas gracias amigo cualquier cosa te voy comentando mi avance, de verdad muchas gracias sos un crack!